# How do I use json data as my input?

Tags: java, json, parsing, input

```
`public class VatCalculator {

    Product product=new Product();
    Airport airport=new Airport();
    VATRates vatrates =new VATRates();
    TaxTable taxtable= new TaxTable();

    //private String vatTable;

   // public VatCalculator(TaxTable taxTable) {
    //    `Z`super(taxTable);
    //    this.vatTable= generateVatTable();
   // }
```

I need to use the taxtable as input in my VatCalculator class. I have created an object but not sure how to get the data from TaxTable. How can I achieve that?

```
I am trying to create a Vat Calculator which calculates based on the taxtable.[vat class][1]
[data][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5MFs.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ajj42.png
```

There is a class called TaxTable which is used to hold the data from a JSON file (DB).
    picture:

```
public class TaxTable implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String taxGroup;
private double onboardSalePct;
private double onboardServicePct;
private double preorderSalePct;
private double preorderServicePct;

@JsonCreator
public TaxTable(@JsonProperty("tax_group") String taxGroup,
                @JsonProperty("onboard_sale_pct") double onboardSalePct,
                @JsonProperty("onboard_service_pct") double onboardServicePct,
                @JsonProperty("preorder_sale_pct") double preorderSalePct,
                @JsonProperty("preorder_service_pct") double preorderServicePct) {
    this.taxGroup = taxGroup;
    this.onboardSalePct = onboardSalePct;
    this.onboardServicePct = onboardServicePct;
    this.preorderSalePct = preorderSalePct;
    this.preorderServicePct = preorderServicePct;
 }


/**
  * @return the taxGroup
  */
 public String getTaxGroup() {
     return taxGroup;
 }

 /**
  * @param taxGroup
  *            the taxGroup to set
  */
 public void setTaxGroup(String taxGroup) {
     this.taxGroup = taxGroup;
 }
```

Comment: Which language you are using ?

Comment: It looks like Java or at least the code contains a super() keyword.

Comment: Please don't segment your question by hiding the code in a picture behind an external link, use the code tags provided to embed them into your question; this will probably attract more people willing to answer.

Comment: Will make the changes. I am using Java.

Answer (score 0):

Are you planning to convert a Java Object into JSON and store it as a String.

You can use the following libraries for that purpose.

- [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson)
- [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind)

Hope it helps!